# The countdown Label won't go down to zero

Tags: python, tkinter

I write a code to create Pomodoro program using Tkinter. This program will count 4 round, first three round will have 25 minute work then five minute break but the last round will be 25 minutes work but long break with 20 minutes, don't worry I set it to second like this, work for 2 second, break for 1 second and long break for 3 second so that it is easy to debug. The problem is when I run program everything work fine except for the count time canvas text 0:00 when it count down to zero it won't become zero, it will freeze at one and then skip to the round time. I have figure out that the problem is with the operation of the code condition below.

```
    if count > 0:
        global clock
        clock = window.after(1000, count_down, count-1)
```

if I change it to >= . It will work fine with out problem even thought if you think about it, it's absolutly unreasonable. Why I say this? copy code in my Github and run it in your program and try to understand my code, if you think about it, the code before I debug should work correct and the code condition with >= 0, canvas text 0:00 should go below to minus like this -1:59, and I MUST know why cause my curiosity will kill me.
Github : https://github.com/KaleidoscopeOdd1612/Pomodoro-program-v.1.0

Comment: When `count == 0` on the iteration where you update the time to `"0:00"` you "immediately" call  `start_time()` and that "immediately" calls `count_down(time)` giving your app no time to display "0:00".

Comment: So you mean that even thought the code have state that this if count > 0: condition are true, it still go on and check the else statement and it "immediately" call start_time() ? I don't understand the code should do this code line first? clock = window.after(1000, count_down, count-1), Also if you are the one who minus my score pose please leave the reason why, cause english is not my first language and I'm try my best to explain, I don't know what I do wrong so you give me minus score?

Comment: When `count == 0` after your code updates the display to "00:00" you call `start_time()` and that calls `count_down(time)` that then sets the display to "00:01" with no delay to pause to allow for the rendering of the "00:00". Comment out line 61 in your source code and you will see that your display updates correctly.

Comment: Wow this is a very new thing to me. So even the code will not finish it process until it has fully run from the first line of code in function until the last line of code in function? So before it has time to display 0:00 it "immediately" call start_time() and that call count_down(time), wow amazing. Thank you so much this is very epic to know, I mean, I always understand that the code will complete it self on line by line but it look like it is not like that huh?